# Always display current version of image on SharePoint page

Tags: document-library, versioning, image, sharepoint-page

I have an image captured out of an email and added to my Content Library every morning. Then I want to display that image dynamically on my SharePoint page.

The issue I am having is that it will always display the version of the image which was at the time when it is added into the SharePoint page.

Is there a way through either embedding or something that would allow the image to change when the image in the SharePoint library changes? So it'll always be the most current version.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be custom solution with following logic.

1. Filter the library by file type e.g. jpeg, .png
2. Filter the library for current month
3. Short the docs by descending order by modified or ID
4. Pick the first item and display it.